# Hide div via cookie detection using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

**Objective:** To hide an embedded Mailchimp subscribe form from subscribed users, by placing a cookie in their browser after subscribing, which causes the form to be hidden via JS.

**What I have so far:**
The Subscribe Form is configured, via Mailchimp's settings, to redirect users to a page that contains the following code:

```
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
         <!--
            Cookies.set('subscriber', 'yes');
         //-->
      </script>



</body>
```

When the user returns to the homepage, this code should execute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         <!--
            if ($.cookie('subscriber')) {
    mc_embed_signup.style.display = 'none';   
}
         //-->
      </script>
```

However the form is still displaying. What am I doing wrong?

Site is http://dev.mistcalls.com
Page with cookie creation code is http://dev.mistcalls.com/subconfirm.html`

Cheers

Comment: Did you check if code inside test `if ($.cookie('subscriber')) {` is executed (with a `console.log()`, for example)?

Comment: And, why writing cookie do you use `Cookies` and when reading do you use `$.cookie`?

Comment: What's with the HTML comment tags within the JS blocks?

Comment: @MarcoS I haven't tried that but will give it a go, cheers. Cookie is in differently as I was referencing guides (relatively new to JS) and didn't know what the difference between them was.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst the HTML comment tags were used in the guide I was referencing.

Comment: What should happen when a user delete their cookies?

Comment: @LGSon The user will see the sign-up form again. It's mainly so that a new subscriber doesn't visit the page a few hours or days later and think the sign-up didn't work correctly the first time.